# How to access parent components inside react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I find myself in need of a generic functionality on all components that is aware of this component's ancestors.

Given that I have a logic that generates a boolean outcome based on component name, I want to know if current component and all its ancestors produce `true` or not.

All components follow functional declaration:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: MyProps): JSX.Element => {
    ...some business logic...
    return(
        <>
            <OtherComponent property={...}>
            </OtherComponent>
        </>);
}
```

Situationally, within the business logic of the `OtherComponent`, I can get a different outcome depending on whether it is used in `MyComponent` or `SomeOtherComponent` and I cannot predict what other components might contain it in the future and how deeply in their hierarchy.

Within any given component, how can I review its ancestry and execute logic on it?

Comment: A react component cannot know what components contain it. This smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you think you need this, and what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: The normal approach is to pass a callback from the parent to the child, and the child can invoke the callback whenever they need to send a message to the parent. Context is also possible. Hard to say for sure with such a vague description of what you're really trying to achieve here, but child components should never know anything about their ancestors.

Comment: @ggorlen Passing data as arguments for component constructor will create maintenance debt in existing components and will generate additional work for creating future components using existing components in future pages. I can get the requirement handled now for all past and future cases generating minimal maintenance.

Comment: @AlexWayne Indeed, I'm asking about a possible solution. My problem is permissions. The UX requirement is to proactively enable/disable UI elements depending on whether the user has read/write/delete permissions. Given an editable table component for many-to-many relationship, it will require write permissions for two different entities, so depending on which two entity editors are among its ancestors, it must request different permissions. The architecture requirement is to not generate individual logic for components - solve this by convention now and for the future.

Comment: @Nomenator Having components accept props (callbacks and data) is no more a maintenance debt than having functions with parameters, or class constructors with parameters. One-way, top-down data flow is the normal way of doing things in React. A worse maintenance situation is taking those same data input dependencies and creating a two-way data flow, tightly coupling child component logic to its ancestor parent tree. It'd be downright horrible, in fact, which is why React is designed as it is, all but preventing it.

Comment: When "prop drilling" becomes a problem and you want to pass down deeply-nested state, as I mentioned, [context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) or a global store like redux is possible. But the problem with this approach is that it's effectively a scoped global, only used for replacing serious prop drilling, and has its own maintenance and debugging problems. Still, though, the data flow is down, and children aren't aware of their ancestors (other than to assume that they're providing context and props, as functions assume they're called with appropriate arguments).

Answer (score 2):

A great way to handle this is with a [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context) ([old docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)). To simplify, it consists of a `Provider`, which wraps all the children, and a hook to be called in the children components to read the data or update the context.

I would highly recommend reading Kent C. Dodds post about [Application State Management](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react). It is an old post, and it will give you the foundation to work with to make what you want to do possible in your app while avoiding some major pitfalls.